# MongoDB nested query boolean issue

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am very clueless about why, despite trying many times with " " and without  " " as well as for the boolean value "true", I get a result when doing the first query - but do not get any sort of result at all when doing the second query? It  is quite puzzling.

[image]

Comment: In the future, please paste text as text, not a screenshot.  It makes it much easier to read on a mobile, and allow copy/paste relevant portions into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `attributes` match.  I assume you are attempting to match documents that contain `"Good for Kids": true` in addition to other fields.

`"attributes":{ "Good for Kids": true}` is looking for a document which contains an attributes object that is identical to the one in the query, i.e. will only match if the attributes field contain a document with only 1 field.

In order to match one field of many, use dot notation to identify the fields in the embedded document like

`"attributes.Good For Kids":true`